# How to login to Android with Security Key?

Tags: security, 7.0-nougat, 8.0-oreo, 2-step-verification, yubikey

I would like to login to my android by my security key. 
The phone has NFC support which is the easiest way to authenticate the login if supported. 
I am thinking how to accomplish the task by 3rd party app. 
The login is well maintained by the OS so not sure if possible at all to change the login way.

Security key: YubiKey Neo (NFC support)
Android: 7.x, 8.x

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not supported by default in Android 7 nor Android Oreo 8.x.