# Is it possible using Yubikey as a login authenticator on lock screen?

Tags: security, settings, usb

This question was already well asked and answered in the negative back in 2017 (see at bottom). However, as I'm about to purchase an Android phone, I'm hoping things have changed. I'm a newbie to Android but the clearest I can be is: How do I setup my Yubikey for use as a first or second authentication factor when logging into my Android device.

For example, before or after I enter my password, I would plug in my Yubico key to finish the login process. To be clear, I'm not referring to account 2fa once inside my phone, but as an authenticator for entering my phone in the first place i.e. as an alternative to fingerprint or swipe patterns. I understand Windows 10 offers this (see link below).

Please let me know which if this is possible at all with an Android device. So far I can't find any even though Yubikey says their product "works with Android". I researched under "Smart Lock" and didn't see anything except Bluetooth, but YubiKey isn't Bluetooth (though they use NFC)

https://www.zdnet.com/article/yubico-security-keys-can-now-be-used-to-log-into-windows-computers/.

---

Previously asked: [How to login to Android with Security Key?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173073/how-to-login-to-android-with-security-key)

> I would like to login to my android by my security key. The phone has
> NFC support which is the easiest way to authenticate the login if
> supported. I am thinking how to accomplish the task by 3rd party app.
> The login is well maintained by the OS so not sure if possible at all
> to change the login way.

Comment: Do you know this article? https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2014/03/unlocking-android-using-otp.html It is a bit older but if I understand correctly mentions exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. The article does seem to address my goal and I will study it as best as my non-technical brain can grasp. Much appreciated.